# What are the possible/likely penalties for violations of the TfL Railway Bylaws other than fare evasion?

Tags: england-and-wales, sentencing, transportation, bylaw

Bob was convicted of a transgression of the TfL railway bylaws other than those pertaining to fare evasion, but can only find [sentencing guidelines](https://www.sentencingcouncil.org.uk/offences/magistrates-court/item/railway-fare-evasion-revised-2017/) for those types of offences.

Are there any general/catch all guidelines for use in the absence of specifically relevant guidelines, or how else may Bob know what type of sentence he may expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

Bob could search the TfL website or the web for TfL railway byelaws and soon arrive here:

https://tfl.gov.uk/corporate/terms-and-conditions/byelaws

Where there is [a link to the TfL Railway Byelaws in PDF format](https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/railway-byelaws.pdf).

Which says:

> 23. Any person who breaches any of the Byelaws commits an offence and may be liable for each such offence to a penalty not exceeding level 3 on the standard scale.

At the time of writing that means a fine of no more than £1000.